# Add constraint based on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints

I have this two tables: `Type` and `Device`.

#### Type

```
CREATE TABLE `Type` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `type` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

#### Device

```
CREATE TABLE `Device` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serial` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `idType` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`serial`,`idType`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`idType`) REFERENCES `Type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Now I need to create a table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDeviceOne` INT NOT NULL,
  `idDeviceTwo` INT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`idDeviceOne`) REFERENCES `Device` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`idDeviceTwo`) REFERENCES `Device` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)
```

In this table I need to have this constraint: `idDeviceOne` and `idDeviceTwo` as to reference to devices with the **SAME** `idType`. How can I add this type of constraint?

Comment: Only trigger logic may solve this task. The constraint cannot access the data out of the current row.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a UK to `Device` table

```
UNIQUE KEY (`idType`, `id`),
```

and reference it from `Test` table

```
CREATE TABLE `Test` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idDeviceOne` INT NOT NULL,
  `idDeviceTwo` INT NOT NULL,
  `idType` INT NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`idType`, `idDeviceOne`) REFERENCES `Device` (`idType, `id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`idType`, `idDeviceTwo`) REFERENCES `Device` (`idType, `id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
)
```

See [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eddaa9a4b915a235f9b70aafe2923181)

Comment: I don't understand how this solution ensure me that `idDeviceOne` and `idDeviceTwo` references to two devices with same `idType`

Comment: Table `test` does not contain `idType` column.

Comment: @th3g3ntl3man .. Added a demo fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_check_devices_types
BEFORE INSERT ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM Device t1
                JOIN Device t2 USING (idType)
                WHERE t1.id = NEW.idDeviceOne
                  AND t2.id = NEW.idDeviceTwo ) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE = 'The devices must have the same type.';
END IF;
END
```

and the same trigger BEFORE UPDATE.

Comment: It doesn't protect against updating one of the referenced device's Type column  to a different value.

Comment: @Serg True. If such operation is possible then checking/protective triggers on `Device` table must exist too.